# mysql sql select last record in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, grouping

I have the following query that provides the results in the screenshot below.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the final result only be the last record for each invoice_number.

I've looked at other questions related to selecting last record by group or subgroup and my sql skills just aren't at a level where I can figure out how I could apply the solutions that were provided in those other questions.

Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    `Invoice`.Amount AS amount,
    zuora.convertDateTimeToGMTOffsetDateTime(`Invoice`.CreatedDate) AS created_date,
    `Invoice`.InvoiceNumber AS invoice_number,
    RatePlanCharge.chargeModel,
    RatePlanCharge.chargeType,
    `InvoiceItem`.`RatePlanChargeId`,
    CASE
        WHEN
            PaymentMethod.type = 'CreditCard'
        THEN
            CONCAT(PaymentMethod.creditCardType,
                    ' (',
                    REPLACE(PaymentMethod.creditCardMaskNumber,
                        '*',
                        ''),
                    ')')
        WHEN
            PaymentMethod.type = 'PayPal'
                AND PaymentMethod.paypalEmail != ''
        THEN
            IF(PaymentMethod.paypalEmail != '',
                CONCAT(PaymentMethod.type,
                        ' (',
                        PaymentMethod.paypalEmail,
                        ')'),
                PaymentMethod.type)
        WHEN PaymentMethod.type = 'WireTransfer' THEN 'Wire Transfer'
        ELSE IF(Invoice.Amount = 0,
            'None Required',
            IF(PaymentMethod.type,
                PaymentMethod.type,
                'Unpaid'))
    END AS payment_method,
    IF(RatePlanCharge.chargeModel != 'Discount'
            AND (RatePlanCharge.chargeType = 'Recurring'
            OR RatePlanCharge.chargeType = 'Usage'),
        TRUE,
        FALSE) AS recurring
FROM
    `InvoiceItem`
        JOIN
    `Invoice` ON `InvoiceItem`.`InvoiceId` = `Invoice`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `RatePlanCharge` ON `RatePlanCharge`.`id` = `InvoiceItem`.`RatePlanChargeId`
        LEFT JOIN
    `InvoicePayment` ON `InvoicePayment`.`invoiceId` = `Invoice`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `Payment` ON `Payment`.`id` = `InvoicePayment`.`paymentId`
        LEFT JOIN
    `PaymentMethod` ON `Payment`.`paymentMethodId` = `PaymentMethod`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `CreditBalanceAdjustment` ON `CreditBalanceAdjustment`.`sourceTransactionId` = `Invoice`.`id`
WHERE
    `Invoice`.`Status` = 'Posted'
        AND Invoice.accountid = '2c92c0f84b786da2014bb934ef664f1b'
```

which provides the following results.  I'd like to limit the final results to just the records that are highlighted in yellow (the last record in each group of invoice numbers):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get single row for each invoice, you can simply add at the end of the query
`GROUP BY Invoice.InvoiceNumber`
But it is not clear from your post what is the criterion/property for 'last' row. Is it the orinal `created_date` property (in the screenshot there are already converted dates which are not distinguishable)? If it is so, then you should first sort resultset by invoce number and then by the created date in descending order (so that the latest record for each invoice is listed as first one and group caluse will take that one), add this 
`ORDER BY Invoice.InvoiceNumber asc, Invoice.CreatedDate desc GROUP BY Invoice.InvoiceNumber`